# Kibana doesn't recognize geolocation field correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, kibana

I'm writing some geolocation data into Kibana 6.6 based on Kibana's documentation, but the data cannot be recognized as geolocation.

I have tried the method 1 and 4 (geo-point as an object, as an array)in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/geo-point.html but neither of them could be recognized correctly as geo-point. Actually they were recognized as number

These are the 2 methods I used for the data format(msg is just a dictionary which stores the information I want to write into Kibana)

```py
action = {
            "index": "loc3",
            "type": "tweet",
            "source": {
                'text' : msg["text"],
                'timestamp': msg["created_at"],
                'location':[msg["loc_long"],msg["loc_lat"]],
                'prediction': msg["prediction"]
                }
            }
```

```py
action = {
            "index": "loc3",
            "type": "tweet",
            "source": {
                'text' : msg["text"],
                'timestamp': msg["created_at"],
                'location':{
                    "lon": msg["loc_long"],
                    "lat": msg["loc_lat"]
                    },
                'prediction': msg["prediction"]
                }
            }
```

Kibana showed me this(using geo-point as object):
[Kibana shows geo-point as number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK9mg.jpg)

The correct recognition should be:
[Kibana correct recognition of geo-point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5w4Q.jpg)

Comment: Did you delete the index and send the data again after you set the mapping of the field to geo_point?

Comment: I used a new index when sending data again

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping you used for the index?